# UISearchController : how to get selected table row index in ios8 (Swift)

Tags: swift, ios8, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uisearchcontroller

I know that searchDisplayController is deprecated in ios8 and I have issue finding the selected row in filtered results using UISearchController

I have the following scenario :

```
     var myObject = PFObject(className:"XX")
     if segue.identifier == "XXXSegue" {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? XXXTableViewController {
            if (self.resultSearchController.active) {

                if let row = self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row {
                    myObject = self.searchResults[row]
                }
            }
            else {
                if let row = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row {
                    myObject = self.objects![row] as! PFObject
                }
            }
           // I will be using myObject for other stuff here 
        }
    }
```

How can I find the selected row index from UISearchController i.e what is the equivalent of :

```
self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row
```

using UISearchController ?

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to wire the segue to the destination view controller in Story Board as a **manual "push" segue from the TableViewController**, rather than as a selection "push" segue from the table view's prototype cell.

Then, in the **tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath** function, manually perform the segue with:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("XXXSegue", sender: tableView)
```

which will pass as an argument either the full, unfiltered table view or the reduced, filtered table view depending on whether your UISearchController is active.

Finally, in the **prepareForSegue** function:

```
if segue.identifier == "XXXSegue" {
  let sender = sender as! UITableView
  let destController = segue.destinationViewController as! XXXTableViewController
  let indexPath = sender.indexPathForSelectedRow()!

  if self.resultSearchController.active {
    destController.objects = self.searchResults[indexPath.row] //filtered array
  } else {
    destController.objects = self.objects[indexPath.row] //full array
  }
}
```

**Edit:  But, to answer your question even more directly, you can try this:

```
if self.resultSearchController.active {
  let updater = self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater as! UITableViewController
  let indexPath = updater.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
...
}
```

This works if you have set **resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self** upon initializing the UISearchController.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

 if tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("XXXSegue", sender : self)
  }
}



override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject?)     
{
//perform your checks upon segue or custom objects 
var indexPath = NSIndexPath()
if self.searchDisplayController.active {
// index path from search table ... 

    indexPath = self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()

} else {
// index path from main table ...
 }    

}
```

Comment: The question has mentioned  it's ```UISearchController ``` not `searchDisplayController`.